# CSS: Shadow creating with :after is bleeding over

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make like a tab folder design with tabs to the left and using the box-shadow around the whole thing except the inactive tabs. My problem is that the shadow I'm creating for the active tab is created using :after and since it's a new stacking context, it's bleeding over on to the content area.

```
 nav li.active:after {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   box-shadow: 0px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }
```

I had a solution before where I put a white box to cover the right shadow created by the box-shadow on the active tab, but I wasn't satisfied so I tried finding another way but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the codepen with a mockup of my code.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmabC

So the big question, do anyone know a good way to get a shadow around the layout without having a shadow bleeding over on to the content area.

Edit: I'm totally up for other ideas then using a :after. The only thing I want to try to avoid is creating a shadow object and positioning it with javascript or use javascript at all the accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED: Please check.**

I've used a shadow image created using Adobe Photoshop this time as a background-image for the `:after` psuedo-selector.

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav ul {
  float: right:
}

nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  background: #ff0;
  position: relative;
  right: -5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav li.active {
  background: #fff;
  right: -4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav li.active:after {
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -10px;
  background: url(http://s28.postimg.org/6lkx1r7gp/bgshadow.png);
  left: -20px;
  opacity: 0.6
}

section {
  background: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Test</li>
      <li>Test 2</li>
      <li>Test 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that also, but I end up with a shadow on one side that is bigger than all the other sides and also it's really tricky not to get a small line of shadow between the li and the section.

Comment: It's a nice solution and it totally works, but my main goal was to try to achieve this effect with pure html and css. Maybe that's impossible and if so, I will probably use your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you mean something like this:

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peuFc

[image]

**CSS:**

```
nav li.active:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: -3px  0  2px rgba(0,0,0,0.20), 
    -3px  -3px  2px rgba(0,0,0,0.10), 
    -3px  3px  2px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove z-index from `li.active` or put it as a negative value, that will put it behind `section`

```
nav li.active {
  background: #fff;
  right: -4px;
  z-index: -999;
}
```

Comment: Then the sections shadow bleed over on to the item. I want a smooth transition that you can't see so it looks like the item and the content is the same page, but with a flap.

Answer (score 0):

Found these two Fiddles in a different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618427/box-shadow-on-3-of-four-sides-of-div)

**Should Work For IE8+:**

http://jsfiddle.net/CVxnZ/

http://jsfiddle.net/76774540/

**The solution:**

```
.shadow.clip-right {
    /*-blur, parent width, parent height+blur, -blur*/
    clip: rect(-8px, 100px, 108px, -8px);
}
```

Comment: The clip solution would have work perfectly if I had known on forehand the widths of the items, but since I don't and I don't want to use javascript it doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway.